# Fonts in windows 10 gone dark

Tags: windows-10, fonts

my windows 10 is having a problem these days. all my fonts in "wireless network" section and in "Start" section gone dark.
it used to be white, but one day it changed to dark :| check the attach pictures please:

[image]

[image]

it doesn't change whatever i do (like changing background or changing main color of theme)

Please help me with this

Comment: Looks like you have the Dark Theme enabled. Try and press **CTRL + T** to disable the Dark Theme.

Comment: i guess so... CTRL+T didn't work. let me try editing reg files

Comment: tried it... but didn't change it ! heeeeelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem !

Windows 10 didn't install the ***Intel HD driver*** well enough.
so i thought it might be the graphics. uninstalled and downloaded the correct driver and installed it by myself.

bang ! it's solved !

P.S: for guys who find it difficult to find the correct driver, i suggest [notebook-driver.com](http://notebook-driver.com) ...

Good Luck